# Document Management using Corda

Tags: corda

I would like to know if Corda can be used as a Document management system in enterprise applications?

If so, where will the documents be stored physically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: Can Corda be used as a Document management system?

Ans: Yes it seems possible. We were analyzing this requirement and its implementation aspect. Eventually we figured out it is possible, though we havent yet started on it.

Q: If so, where will the documents be stored physically?

Ans: Corda allows upload and download of attachments as ZIP/JAR files only. Each document or group of documents will have to be zipped and uploaded as an attachment. The attachment is identified inside the node by hash. Using the hash, the ZIP/JAR file can be opened, saved locally and viewed.

URL -

https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-attachments.html